# asp.net mvc routing id edit or new

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a problem like this. This my default route config.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Index", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "App.Controllers" }
       );
```

I need something like this.

www.xx.com/transaction/index/ -> List Transactions

www.xx.com/transaction/new/ ->New Transaction

www.xx.com/transaction/new/XXX -> Edit Transaction

How can I do?

Comment: Just create `Index()` and `New(int? id)` methods in `TransactionController`

Comment: why not www.xx.com/transaction/edit/XXX for edit transaction? the way it is now you can check if the new action gets XXX or not and then decide if it should edit.

Comment: it doesn't matter. this ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TransactionController 
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View("List", yourList);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult New(int? id)
    {
       var model = new Model();
       if(id.HasValue)
       {
           model = Get(id.Value);
       }
       return View("New", model);
    }
 }
```